# Can you customize a curve by varying thickness and width in blender without making fragmented segments?

Tags: bezier-curves

Im doing a 3d model of a Mac computer and I am stuck at the computer stand. Specifically at the curved stand that starts very thin and becomes thicker as it curves.

I used a bezier curve and I created varying thickness by extruding the individual segments on the curve. Now how to join them so it is one continuous piece and not a bunch of gappy line segments clumped together to make a curve . I have tried segment dissolve as well as every trick in my bag.

Can you customize a curve by varying thickness and width in blender without making fragmented segments?

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you extrude the curve, you can simply increase its resolution and subdivide the segments where smooth shapes needed . You shouldn't recombine anything because if so you can end up with neccesity to continue tweaking resulting shape further on.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately i have used subdivide and smooth until blender itself crashed but the line segments remained visible. Do you have any other suggestions to make this curve appear to be one cohesive object? Also can you please elaborate on increasing its resolution.

Comment: Increasing resolution of the curve is possible in the **Data** tab in **Properties** window (only *before* curve is converted to mesh). I'm not sure what happened with curve after Blender crashed for you, so you might want to [include a .blend file](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file) in comments or in your post.